# Php <input type="file"> problem: it loads only certain files

Tags: php, html, web, file-upload, xampp

I'm doing a form where the user can upload every type of file.

```
<form method="post" action="verifyupload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="userfile">Select file to upload:</label>
    <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile">
</form>
```

and in the "verifyupload.php" file

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_FILES['userfile']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
  echo 'You do not select any file...';
  exit;    
}

and so on...
```

The problem is that it accepts only some files. For example, I uploaded:

-filea.pdf  size: 344 KB

-imagea.jpg size: 216 KB

but it doesn't upload a file like

-filec.pdf size: 2,37 MB

I changed in the Xampp directory, in these files: **php.ini-production, php.ini-development, php.ini** the following lines:

```
upload_max_filesize = 40M
post_max_size = 40M
```

but it doesn't change.

Can you help me, please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If `echo 'You didn't select any file...';` is your real code, you have a parse error by not escaping the quote inside the `didn't`.

Comment: Did you restart after making those changes?

Comment: Hi, no my real code is in Italian. Now I change it, thankyou

Comment: No I  didn't restart. Now I try.

Comment: You will see that it just might fix your problem ;-)

Comment: Ok, I restart Xampp and all works fine. Thankyou! :)

Comment: *Prego!* (welcome).